# what does 'this' refer to in a prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, lexical-scope

Say we have the following example:

```
const Foo = {
  init: function(who) {
    this.me = who;
  },
  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.me);
  }
};
```

Then we have new objects whose prototype references foo:

```
  const b1 = Object.create(Foo);
  const b2 = Object.create(Foo);
  b1.init("Kristopher");
  b2.init("Jane");
  b1.speak();
  b2.speak();
```

The output is the following:

```
Kristopher
Jane
```

But I would have expected "this" to refer to the context of the prototype function. If each new object merely references the prototype, I thought the following would be output:

```
Jane
Jane
```

**Why is this not the case? I thought that since Foo is the shared prototype of b1 and b2, that modifying `this.me` would overwrite the variable for both b1 ad b2?**

Comment: `this` refers to the *current* calling context. In this case, this is the instance created by `Object.create` and stored in, say, `b1`. The prototype is unaffected. If it was, then the whole prototype chain would be pretty useless if everything that descends from a prototype only modifies that prototype.

Comment: @VLAZ awesome thank you. Can you make that an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
const b1 = Object.create(Foo);
const b2 = Object.create(Foo);
```

These lines create two separate instances, using `Foo` as prototype.

```
b1.init("Kristopher");
```

You called `init` with "Kristopher" as argument. `this` in this case is `b1`. `init` would assign "Kristopher" as `b1`'s `me`.

```
b2.init("Jane");
```

You called `init` with "Jane" as argument. `this` in this case is `b2`. `init` would assign "Jane" as `b2`'s `me`.

```
b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

Prints the `me` of both objects.

An easier way to put it is that the value of `this` is not fixed at the time you wrote it (which made you think it was `Foo`). It depends on how the function was called when it was called.

```
const obj = { somefunc() { ... } }

obj.somefunc() // this === obj

const foo = obj.somefunc
foo() // this == window in non-strict mode, this === undefined in strict mode

const arr = []

const bound = obj.somefunc.bind(arr)
bound() // this === arr

obj.somefunc.call(arr) // this === arr
obj.somefunc.apply(arr) // this === arr
```